# Uncaught TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function when using multiple values in chartjs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place the values in a Chartjs from a database. But I am trying it with this code first:

```
function yyy() {

    var chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");

    var dataSetValue = [];

    var count = 10
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        var hardData = [
            {
                name: 'myvalues',
                values: [Math.round(Math.random() * 100), Math.round(Math.random() * 100) - 10]
            }
        ];
        dataSetValue[j] = {
            label: 'Samples',
            fillColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            strokeColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            pointColor: 'rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)',
            pointStrokeColor: '#c1c7d1',
            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
            data: hardData
        }
    }
    console.log(dataSetValue);

    chart = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: "Samples",
            datasets: [
                dataSetValue
            ]
        }
    });

    $('#modal-info').modal();

}
```

I should have 10 lines in my chartjs but what I get instead is this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function`

 This is the stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function
    at i.convertTicksToLabels (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at i.update (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at a (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at Object.o.each (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
    at Object.update (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at t.Controller.updateLayout (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
    at t.Controller.initialize (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
    at new t.Controller (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
    at new t (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at yyy (Admin:872)
```

I get the error, I think, on the part

```
chart = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: "Samples",
        datasets: [
            dataSetValue
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see `ticks` nor `map` in your code. Please update your question is the full stacktrace and show us which line in your code triggers it.

Comment: Even if your code does not directly use `this.ticks` (maybe chartjs has it built in?) we will still need at least the stack trace for the error, and preferably an example showing the error.

Comment: Please see the updated code.